# A Node.js function gives different results while working on my machine and on AWS-Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-request

I have a node function that gets a link to YouTube video and sends a request to https://www.convertmp3.io/ . It's a website that allows to download MP3 from YT.
Then it parses the response HTML to get a direct download link from the document (using a library called "cheerio", but if You're not familiar with it, it's just for scraping the link from HTML), and afterwards opens the link to download the MP3.

My code:

```
const request = require("request")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")

let link = "https://www.convertmp3.io/download/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRSDTE5nWnc"

    const options = {
        url: link,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
        }
    };

    request(options, (error, response, html) => {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)
            const document = $('.infoBox')

            let href = "https://www.convertmp3.io" + document.find("#download").attr('href')

            console.log(href)
        }
    })
```

While working on my machine, this code works correctly. The console.log gives a link which I can open on my browser and see that the mp3 is actually downloading.

But when I run it on Lambda, the link I get has the correct format, but it's simply not working. It redirects to some non-existing domain.
I'm not entirely sure how is this even possible. The only thing I might think about is that the website may think that the program is a bot (logically) and give a wrong link (which sounds pretty bizzare). But I decided to also send some user-agent headers. It didn't work either.

I'm really confused about how can this be possible and don't even know what else to try. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting any errors returned? My initial thoughts is its a CORS issue

Comment: what do you mean when you say its not working? can you show the error? (yeh i thought CORS too)

Comment: No. It runs succesfully and gets the link.

Comment: An example of link from local run (will start a download): https://www.convertmp3.io/download/get/?i=d6DlWnVsNI1Yh2crBDvT3BNIl62I9IR2&e=97&v=RRSDTE5nWnc

An example of link from my lambda run: https://www.convertmp3.io/download/get/?i=AAOvkkSztciCFglmFdBcegew7PHb4TW6&e=80&v=RRSDTE5nWnc
No errors.

Comment: CORS only affects browsers.  If this is all backend code in node.js, CORS should not be relevant.

Comment: They could be giving different responses depending on geography. You want to save the response html somehow and take a look at it.